# Add secondary root partition to Raspberry Pi OS base image (dual-boot)

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi-os, image, bootloader

I want to modify the official Raspberry Pi OS lite image:
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2023-05-03/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz

I want to add a secondary root partition to the image, so I can easily switch between 2 different operating systems.

Since I want to automate the modification of the image file, I cannot use any GUI/desktop program. My Raspberry is not connected to a display so I cannot use any fancy boot manager either (no Berryboot, PINN).
Also I don't want to manually calculate partition sectors, sizes.

What is the common approach to automate the modification of a Raspberry OS image to have dual root partitions?

Answer (score 0):

The Pi will only boot from the first partition on the storage medium.

It is possible to have multiple root partitions (provided they have the same kernel).

PINN installs a minimal OS which then boots selected OS.

---

To use a different root partition just edit `root=PARTUUID=…` entry in `cmdline.txt`.
You also need to edit `/etc/fstab` on the new root to mount the correct root.

```
PARTUUID=…  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. That means I will have to modify /boot when switching between multiple systems. I updated the question so it only asks for how to add a secondary root partition